# How change url and add port socket.io?

Tags: android, sockets

Im trying to learn android and im looking to this app: https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat

How can I change the URL to like *myServerUrl* with port *XX*?

Some code:

```
public class ChatApplication extends Application {

    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, did you even look at the value of `Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL`? Have you tried `http://yourURL:somePort/`?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes ive tried that. Didnt work.

Comment: Was there an exception?

Comment: @cricket_007 just got up "connection failed"-toast on the phone. Im gonna remove the error handling tomorrow and see what the exception says!

Comment: Don't remove the error handling. The exception should be logged in the stacktrace. The Toast isn't what you should look at

Comment: @cricket_007 Im not getting any exceptions. Nothing happens, just the failed to connect toast. If you got the time, maybe you could look through the code? Linked to project on github. If you got the time.

Comment: Are you running a NodeJS socket.io server? I don't really have any experience with that, so I'm afraid I won't be able to help

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I am.